# Ruby: Join and sort filenames

Tags: ruby, sorting

I use the following piece of code to join filenames:

```
Dir["tmp/#{file_prefix}-*"].join " "
```

where `file_prefix = foo`

If I have five files:

```
foo-83.pdf
foo-2.pdf
foo-52.pdf
foo-32.pdf
foo-43.pdf
```

The output would then be unsorted:

```
foo-83.pdf foo-2.pdf foo-52.pdf foo-32.pdf foo-43.pdf
```

How could I modify the code in order to have a sorted result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a built-in sort function.

```
Dir["tmp/#{file_prefix}-*"].sort.join " "
```

However, this will sort in lexographical ordering, i.e. `100 > 99`. In order to avoid this, you could use the block form of `sort`:

```
Dir["tmp/#{file_prefix}-*"].sort {|a, b|
    a.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i <=> b.scan(/\d+/)[0].to_i
}.join " "
```

You can also use `sort_by`, as noted in @Arup's answer.

Comment: sort_by would do well here: ...`sort_by { |filename| filename[/d+/].to_i }`

Comment: That's a nice and short solution. Thanks!

Comment: `sort_by` will outrun `sort` for this use. Any time you have to do calculations to come up with the values to compare inside the block look at `sort_by` first.

Answer (score 4):

Try the below using [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
Dir["tmp/#{file_prefix}-*"].sort_by{|s| s[/\d+/].to_i }.join " "

ary = %w(foo-83.pdf foo-2.pdf foo-52.pdf foo-32.pdf foo-43.pdf)
ary.sort_by{|s| s[/\d+/].to_i }
# => ["foo-2.pdf", "foo-32.pdf", "foo-43.pdf", "foo-52.pdf", "foo-83.pdf"]
```

Comment: This just plain doesn't even work... -1 (try it in irb: `['foo 100 bar', 'foo 200 bar', 'foo 300 bar', 'foo 99 bar'].sort_by{|s| s[/\d+/] }.join " "` --> `"foo 100 bar foo 200 bar foo 300 bar foo 99 bar"`)

Comment: wait, but this will order, say, `foo-100.pdf` **before** `foo-2.pdf`, which is definitely wrong...

Comment: This still performs a lexographic sort, as shown bo @Doorknob's comment.  To make it sort in numeric order, change `s[/\d+/]` to `s[/d+/].to_i`.